# ofstream: cannot open the file

Tags: c++, ofstream

I face an ofstream problem and the program cannot open the file that I want to write. The minimal, complete and varifiable code is showed as follows:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string root_path = "E:\\160818\\";
    string file_path = root_path + "haar_data.txt";

    ofstream haar_file(file_path.c_str());

    if(!haar_file) // < -------- File cannot be open
    {
        cout<<"Error opening file for writing\n";
        return 1;
    }
    haar_file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

My compiler is VS2008. The output in the screen is

> Error opening file for writing.

What is the error? I want open this file to write something.

Comment: Does the file haar_data.txt exist, or do you want to create it ? Is your program allowed to create/modify files in this path ? (Maybe run as administrator or something)
(Oh, and maybe try replace \\ with /, not sure it works on Windows, but it's worth giving it a try)

Comment: You don't have permission to create or open the file. Simple!

Comment: BTW `main` returns `int`, always.

Comment: @bisthebis The file is existed and empty. And I want open this file to write something in it.

Comment: probably the file has permission settings that your program is not allowed to write to it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not always, in VS, `void main()` is OK. I found that I haven't the premission to write it. But how I get the right in Windows 10?

Comment: I have found the problem, which I used a file path containing Chinese in my real code.

Comment: @Lee: No, even in VS, it is wrong. That the compiler accepts it is an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have compiled your code and used it, it worked.

---

Note that you haven't included iostream in your provided code therefore I had to add it because of the 'cout' expression.
Note that since c++11 you don't need to use .C_str() to open a file.
Note that if your file doesn't exist, because you use ofstream (opens with ios::out), your file will be created anyway.
Are you using admin rights?
Is your path correct (folder name mistake?)

Comment: Yeah, my folder name contains Chinese, which leads to this problem.

Comment: How would one use "admin rights" in this case to write to the file?  Would it be a simple `sudo ./executable` at run time or is it something that needs to be done in the code?